# Public schema is not defined in security definer function's search_path but it is still accessible

Tags: sql, postgresql

When I define a function such as this one:

```
create or replace function test_func_a()
returns table(search_path name[], public_func_result text) as $$
  select current_schemas('true'), trim(' does it work ');
$$ language sql stable security definer set search_path = pg_temp;
select test_func_a();
                test_func_a                
-------------------------------------------
 ("{pg_catalog,pg_temp_2}","does it work")
```

Why am I still able to use a function in the public schema such as trim or current_schemas for that matter? Shouldn't it only work if I explicitly use public.trim()?

Functions that are in schemas that I've created do not work in the same fashion. In this example I attempt to use a function in the util schema without setting it in the search_path:

```
create or replace function test_func_b()
returns table(search_path name[], public_func_result text) as $$
  select current_schemas('true'), trim_whitespace(' does it work ');
$$ language sql stable security definer set search_path = pg_temp;
ERROR:  function trim_whitespace(unknown) does not exist
LINE 3:   select current_schemas('true'), trim_whitespace(' does it ...
                                          ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need 
to add explicit type casts.
```

Outside of functions, my search_path is set as this:

```
select current_schemas('true');
                      current_schemas                       
 ------------------------------------------------------------
 {pg_temp_2,pg_catalog,public,util}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look inside your `public` schema. Do you see TRIM? current_schemas? No, they're not there. Have a read of this https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-schemas.html

On the public schema:

> By default [...] tables (and other objects) are automatically put into
>   a schema named "public". Every new database contains such a schema.
>   [...] There is nothing special about the public schema except that it
>   exists by default. It can be dropped, too.

So how is it resolving `current_schemas`?

> In addition to public and user-created schemas, each database contains
>   a pg_catalog schema, which contains the system tables and all the
>   built-in data types, functions, and operators. pg_catalog is always
>   effectively part of the search path. If it is not named explicitly in
>   the path then it is implicitly searched before searching the path's
>   schemas. This ensures that built-in names will always be findable.
>   However, you can explicitly place pg_catalog at the end of your search
>   path if you prefer to have user-defined names override built-in names.

Have a look inside `pg_catalog` (under `Catalogs` in PGAdmin), `current_schemas` is in the function list there.

And the built-in function TRIM is a keyword which PG recognises, see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I suppose I should have checked pg_catalog considering it was being returned right there in my current_schemas... the mysteries of banging one's head against the wall.